# Special 8-Crown Not Appearing

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I still can't find the Special 8-Crown Level.

- I've beat every Level with Mario (Regular and Special)
- I've beat every Level with Luigi (Regular and Special)
- I have a Gold flag on each level (Regular and Special)
- I have all the Star Coins on each level (Regular and Special)

It doesn't appear on the Regular or Special world.

My save file only shows 4 Stars and I'm not sure what I am missing.

Any clues why this would happen?

Comment: When you say you've beaten every level, are you including Champion's Road? I believe that is required for the 5th star.

Comment: @originaluser: You've got the wrong game; this is 3D Land, not 3D World.

Comment: I went back and replayed both Level 8 castles and nothing.  The only thing I can think of is maybe using the Invincibility Leaf DOES matter. But, I'm not sure which levels I used it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Special_8), these are the five requirements for each save file star:

> - Beat all the levels in the first eight worlds.
>   While not necessary, the player must also not use the Invincibility Leaf nor the P-Wing on all levels for glittering stars.
> - Beat Bowser on World 8-Castle 2.
> - Clear Special 8, then beat Bowser again in World 8-Castle 2.
> - Collect every Star Medal in every level.
> - Hit the top of the flagpole on all levels, and finish all levels as both Mario and Luigi. (The top of the flagpole does not need to be hit with both brothers.)

The info in your question suggests you may need to beat Bowser in 8-C2 again for the fifth star to trigger.

Comment: There's a special star graphic if you do the 5 star requirements without the super guide appearing, but it's not worth it.

Comment: I did that and it did not show up.  There is something that is keeping me from getting that 5th star, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: I Double Checked.  Then, I tried both World 8 Castles in a row.  Then, I Triple (and very slowly) checked each level.  Doh!  I was missing a gold flag on W5-3!  Thanks for the answer.